# Changing browser title when loading a file

Tags: javascript, browser

I am loading a file into a new browser tab from a URL via JavaScript.  In this case it is a PDF file, but it can be other types too.  It all works fine except that the browser tab always says "untitled".  I want it to (ultimately) say the file name.  For now I am just using "My Title".  I am using this:

```
var loadFile = function (url) {
    var newwin = window.open(url);
    newwin.addEventListener("load", function() {
        newwin.document.title = 'My Title';
    });
};
```

When I run it through the Chrome debugger, I see `newwin.document.title` is blank.  Very surprisingly, it is still blank *after* the assignment. I'm really lost.

Comment: I should add, just to be clear, that the event listener is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Add **false** parameter to your event listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadFile = function (url) {
var newwin = window.open(url, "MsgWindow", "width=400, height=400");
window.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    newwin.document.title = "Loading file....";
    console.log("load event detected!");
}, false);
loadFile('http://www.google.com');
</script>
```

*NB: Mark this as answer*

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Chrome - not even loading google.com

Comment: Are you sure chrome has allowed popup?

Comment: It is showing up in a new tab as I wish.  Everything works fine with my original code except that the title is "untitled".

Comment: do you load local file?

Comment: The file is being served up, and it is on the same base URL.